# Is there a standard way to represent conversion from one object to another in Scala?

Tags: scala

I made a trait in Scala.

```
trait Convert {
  def to[T]: T
}
```

Then in my class I have:

```
case class SourceCode(code: String) {
  override def to[IndentedCode]: IndentCode = { ... }
}
```

Here I am representing a way to convert one object into another. When I want to convert I use as such:

```
sourceCode.to[IndentedCode].toString
```

Is there a standard way to represent conversion from one type to another? Would people use implicits as they could do automatic type conversion, but then how would you chain them together to go from one to another?

Comment: I think implicit conversions are often the way to go.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're asking here. Is `IndentCode` a typo for `IndentedCode`? Do you mean for that to be an unconstrained type parameter? Is `SourceCode` supposed to extend `Convert`? In any case please don't use implicit conversions for this kind of thing, or at least think really hard before you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's worth taking a step back here and defining what you're doing here.  When you talk about type conversion, you're talking about `A => B`.  The implementation of `Convert` you have  only has `T` (in this case, `B`).  It doesn't specify what it is converting from.  Start by describing just what you need...

```
type Convert[A,B] = A => B
```

You could then provide an implementation for whatever values of `A` and `B` you want...

```
object int2string extends Convert[Int,String] {
  def apply(in: Int): String = in.toString
}
```

Using it of course is obvious...

```
int2string(67)
```

If you aren't using implicits you can stop there.  You're done.

If you are using implicits, you can describe a method that allows any type to convert for which an `implicit Convert` is available for...

```
implicit class ConvertableOps[A](a: A) {
  def to[B](implicit convert: Convert[A,B]): B = convert(a)
}
```

Which would let you then let you express the above as...

```
67.to[String]
```

or...

```
67.to[SourceCode]
```

or whatever else you wanted, assuming that an implicit `Convert[A,B]` is in scope.